# How to sort querysets from different models based on two fields?

Tags: python, django

I have querysets from different models which have only two fields in common: `datetime` and `dt_created`, and I would like to sort the objects first on `datetime` and then on `dt_created`, so that objects with the same `datetime` are sorted based on field `dt_created`.

How can I do that ?

Until now I was able to combine and sort the queryset with `datetime` like this:

```
lst_qs = list(qs_trades) + list(qs_deposits) + list(qs_withdrawals)
sorted_lst = sorted(lst_qs, key=lambda x: x.datetime)
```

Comment: is there any interrelations between these three models? Can you share the models? If there is no relation between these models, then your approach is probably the best, unless you consider remodeling or redesigning the tables (or models).

Comment: @ruddra there is no direct relation between the models and many fiels are differents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
lst_qs = list(qs_trades) + list(qs_deposits) + list(qs_withdrawals)
sorted_lst = sorted(lst_qs, key=lambda x: (x.dt_created, x.datetime))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class Meta:

```
class Example(models.Model):
...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['datetime', 'dt_created']
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will sort objects of one queryset independently of other querysets. I need to combine querysets and sort objects of all querysets.